# For propensity score estimation, why would one want to use a spline to fit/estimate it?

Tags: splines, propensity-scores

I have read a few papers in causal inference where the authors would use a spline to estimate a propensity score model. I am wondering what would motivate such a decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to find propensity, typically, you can only observe pairs of the form $(x_i, b_i)$, where $x_i$ is the $i$th instance of the covariate vector, and $b_i$ could be something like whether the $i$th instance underwent treatment or not.

From these, you somehow need to build a propensity function $f(x)$, but how? Broadly speaking, you could do this by:

1. binning close values of $x$ if needed (say if $x$ is continuous) to $\bar{x}_j$ (the $j$th bin)
2. finding the empirical distribution of $b$s in each $\bar{x}_j$
3. interpolating and/or regularizing the results of 2. to obtain $f(x)$

There are several ways of doing 3., each with bias-variance tradeoffs, availability of software packages, interpretability of results, and so on. Splines are considered one reasonable solution.

See [Over-fitting of Propensity Score Models-does it matter?](https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-00859762/document) for more about the general question of 3.

Comment: What is the difference between using a regular approach like a logit propensity score versus a spline? What does a spline do that normal approaches dont offer?